# Archlinux shift+numeric keypad

Tags: numeric, shift, archlinux, keypad

the problem is that in any application ( Netbeans, Xfce, etc... ) when I want to e.g. check whole text to the end of a line, I use shift+7, 
( I'm working on a notebook - don't have separate 'Home'/'End'/..., so I use the numeric keypad )
 but on Archlinux it writes just '7' ( same in console ).
Is there any way to disable it??

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score -1):

Turn on *numlock* by clicking the numlock key on the keyboard and it should work without you having to press shift.